# Some persistent data is not stored issue in Scorm

Tags: scorm

I have a question in scorm,Actually now i have a scorm package created in lectora and its launching and working fine for me .But in the middle one alert is showing "Some persistent data was not stored" .When i googled it i got that its due to the exceeding of suspend_data reporting from the scorm package(4k for scorm 1.2 and 64 k for scorm 2004).

How can i crack the problem through my code or how can i set the maximum limit in my scorm adaptor  because i cant change the package.

Hope you understand the problem very eagerly waiting for your reply

Thanking You

Arun KG

Comment: do you have access to the SCORM player's code, on the LMS itself?

Comment: Yes what should i do with it?

Comment: You can change the length check to something more than 4K characters. I had the same problem as you and in order to work around it, I violated the SCORM protocol, adding more characters to the CMIString4096 data type. It's a harmless violation, since all contents will continue to play

Comment: Thanks ,Actually how can i do the same.Will you please explain?and in which file?

Comment: Your SCORM engine should be inside a javascript file. It largely depends on the engine itself, but you should look for the Regular Expression that is checked when setting the suspend_data. It should check against 4096 characters. Perhaps even just looking for "4096" will help you

Comment: Hi there, could someone please help me with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008375/cannot-retrieve-previously-saved-data-from-lms-scorm-2004) question/issue about SCORM 2004? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen solutions where developers have hijacked some of the other read/write CMI fields to store arbitrary data. For example, `cmi.comments` gets you another 4K in SCORM 1.2. SCORM 2004 gives you quite a few more (`cmi.interactions.n.description`, `cmi.objectives.n.description`, ...).

Most of these alternative fields are not mandatory, so your target LMS may not support them.